# Rotate non-square image in lwuit

Tags: image, rotation, lwuit

I'm trying to rotate a lwuit image.  The problem is that the image size is 400x300, so when I rotate it, it gets cut.  Lwuit documentation says that the rotate method  assumes a square image, and that's the problem.  Is there some other way to rotate the image?.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
javax.microedition.lcdui.Image lcduiImage=(javax.microedition.lcdui.Image) imagen.getImage();
javax.microedition.lcdui.Image lcduiImageRotada=javax.microedition.lcdui.Image.createImage(lcduiImage, 0, 0, lcduiImage.getWidth(), lcduiImage.getHeight(), Sprite.TRANS_ROT90);
imagen=Image.createImage(lcduiImageRotada);
```